# unknown host services.gradle.org

Tags: android, gradle

i have downloaded code for an android app. when I open it it just shows buiding and does not load. Only I was able to load it was by restarting sytem in safe mode.When It was loaded it shows "unknown host services.gradle.org"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
1. Go to File->Setting->Build, Execution, Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle
2. Under Project level Setting find gradle directory
```